# How to make a Binary search tree using array but not using linked list?

Tags: arrays, binary-search-tree

I am able to make a binary search  tree using linked list. But I can not able to make it using linear array.

Comment: Sorry, this homework assignment is for you, not us.

Answer (score 0):

Just a general direction -

I would use the array indexes as the children - like a heap data structure.

for vertex at index i, children nodes are at 2i+1 (left chiled) and 2i+2 (right chiled).

father node is at [i-1)/2)].

good luck